# Laravel redirect not working inside controller function that mapped from post route inside iframe

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm trying to redirect the page to some route ,the redirection is applied iinside a method that recieves form data and processes it .Now if data is authenticated the application now has to redirect to the main page ,the problem is the main page is loaded inside the frame that I specified it for the form to be targeted to .I need the whole application to redirect to main .Here is the code
Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;
use App\Models\admin\Admins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class Account extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
    public function login(){
        if(session() ->exists('admin')){
            return redirect(URL::to('/').'/admin/main');
        }
        return view('admin/login');
    }

    public function dologin(){
        $email = \request()->email;
        $pass = \request()->password;
        $admin = new Admins();
        $admin_data = $admin -> getAdmin($email);
        if($admin_data <> null){
            if(md5($pass) === $admin_data -> password){
                session() -> put('admin' ,array('admin_id' => $admin_data -> id ,
                    'admin_name' => $admin_data -> name ,
                    'admin_email' => $admin_data -> email ,
                    'admin_mobile' => $admin_data -> mobile));
                Redirect::to(URL::to('/').'/admin/main');
            }else{
                return json_encode(array('succ' => false ,'cause' => 'خطأ في اسم المستخدم أو كلمة المرور'));
            }
        }else{
            return json_encode(array('succ' => false ,'cause' => 'لم يتم العثور على البريد الإلكتروني'));
        }

    }
    public function main(){
        if(session() ->exists('admin')) {
            return view('admin.main');
        }
        return redirect(URL::to('/').'/admin/login');
    }
}
```

And my form view ,with iframe hidden above it :

```
<iframe class="d-flex w-100 d-none" id="admin-login" name="admin-login"></iframe>
            <form class="form w-100 fv-plugins-bootstrap5 fv-plugins-framework" novalidate="novalidate" id="login-form" target="admin-login" method="post" action="{{route('admin.dologin')}}">
                @csrf
                <!--begin::Heading-->
                <div class="text-center mb-10">
                    <!--begin::Title-->
                    <h1 class="mb-3 color-annay-gray">سجل الدخول</h1>
                </div>
                <!--begin::Heading-->
                <!--begin::Input group-->
                <div class="fv-row mb-10 fv-plugins-icon-container">
                    <!--begin::Label-->
                    <label class="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder color-annay-gray">البريد الإلكتروني</label>
                    <!--end::Label-->
                    <!--begin::Input-->
                    <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off">
                    <!--end::Input-->
                    <div class="fv-plugins-message-container invalid-feedback"></div></div>
                <!--end::Input group-->
                <!--begin::Input group-->
                <div class="fv-row mb-10 fv-plugins-icon-container">
                    <!--begin::Wrapper-->
                    <div class="d-flex flex-stack mb-2">
                        <!--begin::Label-->
                        <label class="form-label fw-bolder fs-6 mb-0 color-annay-gray">كلمة المرور</label>
                        <!--end::Label-->
                        <!--begin::Link-->
                        <a href="{{URL::to('/').'/admin/resetpass'}}" class="link-primary fs-6 fw-bolder colo-main">نسيت كلمة المرور ؟</a>
                        <!--end::Link-->
                    </div>
                    <!--end::Wrapper-->
                    <!--begin::Input-->
                    <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
                    <!--end::Input-->
                    <div class="fv-plugins-message-container invalid-feedback"></div></div>
                <!--end::Input group-->
                <!--begin::Actions-->
                <div class="text-center">
                    <!--begin::Submit button-->
                    <button type="submit" id="sign_in_submit" class="btn btn-lg w-100 mb-5 annay-admin-btn">
                        <span class="indicator-label">دخول</span>
                        <span class="indicator-progress"> - الرجاء الانتظار ...
                                    <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle ms-2"></span></span>
                    </button>
                    <!--end::Submit button-->
                    <!--begin::Separator-->
                </div>
                <!--end::Actions-->
                <div class="color-error-msg"></div>
            </form>
```

Here is my route

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\admin\Account;
use App\Http\Controllers\customer\ClassesController;
use App\Http\Controllers\customer\ItemsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\customer\OrdersController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'customer', 'as' => 'customer.'], function () {
    Route::get('/classes/{id}', [ClassesController::class, 'show'])->name('classes');
    Route::get('/items/{id}', [ItemsController::class, 'show'])->name('items');
    Route::get('/item/{id}', [ItemsController::class, 'item'])->name('item');
    Route::get('/order/{id}', [OrdersController::class, 'order'])->name('order');
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('/' ,[Account::class, 'login']);
    Route::get('/login', [Account::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    Route::post('/dologin', [Account::class, 'dologin'])->name('dologin');
    Route::get('/main', [Account::class, 'main'])->name('main');
});
```

Comment: The controller function I do the route in is called "dologin"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
return redirect()->route('admin.login');

Answer (score 0):

**Try** `return redirect("admin/main")` don't have to use Url::to(). redirect will match the url from your **web.php** or you can use `redirect()->route("here your route name")`.